# is light a conduit for the transfer of present information to it's arrived distination

Tags: astrophysics

If light took 15 billion years to arrive from a distant star and energy from that star was shut off how long would it take for the darkness  to arrive?

Comment: Light as a conduit for the instantaneous transfer of information is not part of mainstream physics. I have voted to close this question as *off topic* for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it takes 15 billion years for the light to travel from a star to Earth, and the star suddenly ceases to produce light it will take **drum roll** **exactly** 15 billion years for the darkness to arrive.

As for the argument that "the speed of darkness is instantaneous," I *highly* recommend the VSauce video [What is the Speed of Dark?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTvcpdfGUtQ)  It explores this concept with the correct level of rigor to prevent mistaken conclusions.